# Within a generation, fermion species' mass seems like it could have an effect on how many of the fundamental forces it interacts with. Is this true?

Tags: fermions, neutrinos, quarks, elementary-particles, leptons

So, fermions all interact with the gravitational force and the weak force. All fermion species.

Now, if you eliminate from that list, the particles that don't interact with electromagnetism, you remove the neutrionos, the least massive fermions in any given generation, and are left with two groups of more massive fermions, quarks and leptons. Now remove the particles that don't interact with the strong force. You remove the electrons/positrons, the second least massive group in each generation. You are left only with the most massive fermions in any given generation, the quarks.

Is there there a connection, and if so what is the connection between the mass that a particle has, the generation that it belongs to, and the number of forces that it interacts with?

Comment: What about the singlets from each generation?

Comment: @Triatticus I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are forgetting the right handed parts of each generation that don't interact weakly but do interact electromagnetically

Comment: The right-handed neutrino is presumably the heaviest fermion (its Majorana mass is at GUT scale, according to the see-saw mechanism), and yet it does not interact at all. So your premise is wrong.